# Can TypeScript infer the properties of an object?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I'm attempting to define a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to verify if a variable of `unknown` type has a `data` property. My code is defined below.

```js
type DataObject = {
  data: string
};

function hasDataProperty(myObject: unknown): myObject is DataObject {
    return typeof myObject === "object" &&
        !!myObject &&
        typeof myObject.data === "string";
}
```

[Try it on the Typescript Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=68&pln=5&pc=77#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOB5ARgKwgY2FAvFAbwFgAoKKAEwTgC4oBnYAJwEsA7Ac1IF8BuU0gDMArm2wsA9mygALOPXiIACkwmQmoABQBbEKgzY6ogNZsJAdzYBKOrv1YcLerGr3shUuXJMIwYU2lQSAlBKDt0BzxcfAAiCQjsGKgAMmTPLwyAQkzwgxxU9IzyXIcAOjl6JEsVNQgNEE0YqkQYqxS0siLyIIgQsL0E4FLmuCjYxlZOGP4SbiA)

If you open the playground, you'll see an error on line 8 indicating `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'object'.`, which makes sense, because I haven't verified that the `data` property exists on `myObject`.

I've tried using both `"data" in myObject` and `myObject.hasOwnProperty("data")` to check if the property exists, but neither seem to affect TypeScript's inferred type of `myObject` to include `data`, it is still a plain `object` type.

I could change the function signature to `hasDataProperty(myObject: any)` or use a type assertion to change the type from `unknown`, but both of those options ignore the object's actual properties, which could result in bugs in the type guard's logic.

Is there a way to determine if `myObject` has a `data` property without the use of type assertions or `any`?

Comment: After making some research it looks like there is no type-safe way to do that, and unfortunately cast `any` is unavoidable here.

Comment: @zerkms and perfectly acceptable... So it seems a type guard has not to be type safe, after all.

Comment: @A.Chiesa "and perfectly acceptable" --- it depends, I don't believe I know JS better than tsc.

Comment: @zerkms if you don't know if code as complicated as `myObject && typeof myObject.data === "string"` can throw errors or not in JS, you shouldn't work with TS. But I think you know, and you're just pretending for the sake of it ;) TS _is_ JS with types, and truthy and falsy values are really the basics.

Comment: @A.Chiesa I know yep, but I don't trust myself - I make mistakes, and `tsc` does not* :-) And I agree though that this would be a _very rare_ case when `any` is unavoidable.

Comment: @zerkms I thought a lot about your assertion and there is merit in the checking of property keys. I elaborated (quite a bit) my original answer with a proposal for an type guard factory, with type safe definitions. Thanks for the arguing! It was a useful discussion.

Comment: @A.Chiesa at that degree of safety I'd simply take `io-ts` https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts because you implemented a very shallow version of it now

Comment: @zerkms io-ts seems interesting, but I fear the complexity of it for the introduction in my team. Is the learning curve as steep as it seems? Skimming through the docs I see a lot of pretty esoteric examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201625/discussion-between-zerkms-and-a-chiesa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do appreciate zerkms' answer, I would prefer to have a generic and type-safe method to determine if a parameter exists in an object.

I did some further exploring and found a solution that I like better. [I found this issue in the TypeScript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10485), which has the code block for `hasKey`, a type-safe way to determine if a key exists in an object.

```js
export function hasKey<K extends string>(k: K, o: {}): o is { [_ in K]: {} } {
  return typeof o === 'object' && k in o
}
```

While I would prefer to use the `in` operator, `hasKey` is an acceptable alternative for now. Here is how I can use it in my type guard:

```js
type DataObject = {
  data: string
};

export function hasKey<K extends string>(k: K, o: {}): o is { [_ in K]: {} } {
  return typeof o === 'object' && k in o
}

function hasDataProperty(myObject: unknown): myObject is DataObject {
    return typeof myObject === "object" &&
      !!myObject &&
      hasKey("data", myObject) &&
      typeof myObject.data === "string";
}

// Testing hasKey
const myThing: object = {};
if (hasKey("myVariable", myThing)) {
  console.log(myThing.myVariable); // This does not error
} else {
  console.log(myThing.myVariable); // This errors
}
```

Strangely, the above TypeScript issue was closed and "fixed", although the `in` operator still doesn't act as a type-guard for objects. [There is a new issue here which seems to track something similar](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732), although that one is still open.

Comment: I seriously do not understand what problem this solution solves. You still have to check for each property presence, you still have to check the type of each property, your code still returns the same result of a simple one liner. If the DataObject contains more than one property, you still have to duplicate the checking code for each property and keep it updated (e.g. if you change the name of the "data" field in the interface, this code is going to give you a false security). Interfaces exist only when compiling: if you want "true" type safety, you must use classes and `instanceof`.

Comment: @A.Chiesa, I think you're focusing too much on the type guard, which is just one example where something like this could be used. 
My question could be simplified to: what is a typesafe alternative to `"someKey" in myObject`. Having that answered allows me to use `unknown` in cases where it might be useful, potentially in type guards, but also other cases.

Comment: Oh right, I see - it's cool. You should type it as `o is { [_ in K]: unknown } {` though perhaps. Also, given you type `o: {}` you probably don't need `typeof o === 'object'` check as well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that the bit `typeof myObject === "object"` tells the compiler that the myObject instance *is* effectively an Object. So TypeScript assumes in the rest of the expression that myObject is of type `{}`, which obviously is not.

I would let go of `unknown`, in this method, and apply KISS:

```
function isDataObject(myObject: any): myObject is DataObject {
    return myObject && typeof myObject.data === "string";
}
```

**Edit** after extensive discussions with zerkms and Adam.
Well, I'm quite stubborn, so I continued picking on zerkms solutions. Turns out there *could* be a safer way to build Type Guards, and I'm going to propose it in the following.

My idea is to use the compile time checks of the compiler to check a "blueprint" of the type guard. I'm going to define a ValidatorDefinition as in the following:

```js
export type ValidatorTypes =
  | "string"
  | "boolean"
  | "number"
  | "array"
  | "string?"
  | "boolean?"
  | "number?";

export type ValidatorDefinition<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends string
    ? "string" | "string?"
    : T[key] extends number
    ? "number" | "number?"
    : T[key] extends boolean
    ? "boolean" | "boolean?"
    : (T[key] extends Array<infer TArrayItem>
        ? Array<ValidatorDefinition<TArrayItem>>
        : ValidatorTypes);
};
```

So each property of a simple type must be associated to a string defining exactly the kind of validation.
Then, I'm going to build a TypeGuard factory:

```js
function typeGuardFactory<T>(
  reference: ValidatorDefinition<T>
): (value: any) => value is T {
  const validators: ((propertyValue: any) => boolean)[] = Object.keys(
    reference
  ).map(key => {
    const referenceValue = (<any>reference)[key];
    switch (referenceValue) {
      case "string":
        return v => typeof v[key] === "string";
      case "boolean":
        return v => typeof v[key] === "boolean";
      case "number":
        return v => typeof v[key] === "number";
      case "string?":
        return v => v[key] == null || typeof v[key] === "string";
      case "boolean?":
        return v => v[key] == null || typeof v[key] === "boolean";
      case "number?":
        return v => v[key] == null || typeof v[key] === "number";
      default:
        // we are not accepting null/undefined for empty array... Should decide how to
        // handle/configure the specific case
        if (Array.isArray(referenceValue)) {
          const arrayItemValidator = typeGuardFactory<any>(referenceValue[0]);
          return v => Array.isArray(v[key]) && v[key].every(arrayItemValidator);
        }
        // TODO: handle default case
        return _v => false;
    }
  });
  return (value: T): value is T =>
    (value && validators.every(validator => validator(value))) || false;
}
```

Example usage:

```
type DataObject = {
  data: string
};
const hasDataObject = typeGuardFactory<DataObject>({ data: "string" });
```

The nice thing is that if you misspell the definition of the Validator, you'll get compile time errors.

Some simple unit testing code:

```js
const validatorForDataObject = typeGuardFactory({ data: "string" });

const testCases: { value: any; expected: boolean }[] = [
  { value: null, expected: false },
  { value: undefined, expected: false },
  { value: { data: 0 }, expected: false },
  { value: { data: "0" }, expected: true }
];

testCases.forEach(testCase => {
  const testResult = validatorForDataObject(testCase.value);
  if (testResult === testCase.expected) {
    console.info(`Success (with value ${testResult})`, testCase.value);
  } else {
    console.error(`Fail (with value ${testResult})`, testCase.value);
  }
});

interface AnotherType {
  stringProp: string;
  numberProp: number;
  booleanProp: boolean;
  nullableStringProp?: string;
  nullableNumberProp?: number;
  nullableBooleanProp?: boolean;
  arrayProp: {
    data: string;
  }[];
}

const validatorForAnotherType = typeGuardFactory<AnotherType>({
  stringProp: "string",
  numberProp: "number",
  booleanProp: "boolean",
  nullableStringProp: "string?",
  nullableNumberProp: "number?",
  nullableBooleanProp: "boolean?",
  arrayProp: [
    {
      data: "string"
    }
  ]
});

const testCases2: { value: any; expected: boolean }[] = [
  { value: null, expected: false },
  { value: undefined, expected: false },
  { value: { data: 0 }, expected: false },
  {
    value: {
      stringProp: "string",
      numberProp: 1,
      booleanProp: true,
      nullableStringProp: "string",
      nullableNumberProp: 1,
      nullableBooleanProp: false,
      arrayProp: [{ data: "" }]
    },
    expected: true
  },
  {
    value: {
      stringProp: "string",
      numberProp: 1,
      booleanProp: true,
      nullableStringProp: null,
      nullableNumberProp: null,
      nullableBooleanProp: null,
      arrayProp: []
    },
    expected: true
  },
  {
    value: {
      stringProp: "string",
      numberProp: 1,
      booleanProp: true,
      nullableStringProp: "string",
      nullableNumberProp: null,
      nullableBooleanProp: null,
      arrayProp: [{ data: "" }, { data: "" }, { data: 0 }]
    },
    expected: false
  },
  {
    value: {
      stringProp: "string",
      numberProp: 1,
      booleanProp: true,
      nullableStringProp: "string",
      nullableNumberProp: null,
      nullableBooleanProp: null,
      arrayProp: [{ data: "" }, { data: "" }, { data: 0 }]
    },
    expected: false
  },
  {
    value: {
      stringProp: null,
      numberProp: 1,
      booleanProp: true,
      nullableStringProp: null,
      nullableNumberProp: null,
      nullableBooleanProp: null,
      arrayProp: []
    },
    expected: false
  }
];

testCases2.forEach(testCase => {
  const testResult = validatorForAnotherType(testCase.value);
  if (testResult === testCase.expected) {
    console.info(`Success (with value ${testResult})`, testCase.value);
  } else {
    console.error(`Fail (with value ${testResult})`, testCase.value);
  }
});
```

The funny thing is that, still, the validation code makes plenty of use of `any`, but everything else in the porcelain world outside the guard seems pretty solid. It's just a sketch, but I think it shows some potential.

[The full snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=170&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBqBDANgSwCYYzQAqywAznALwCwAUHHAD5wBE5MUOAdgOav1GLVgCMIELMAzcBDZm24BXALYjgUWULYYoUDIk3z2nHrwD8h4WIlTuFwUaWr1FgNz16oSLARl02fEJoABFgADMeHBgcCG4AHmIAPmo4AG8HAG0Aa2BEOB44HMQIMLhiAF0ALjLs3PK4UBhgbjxKDi4%20B0YzNnbTViM%20vns5RmriWsR6xubWuCc1KC64HtYF9QHhdagRxjGaoumQJpbKa0lpZdXz2022G%20ldveqACgnDhuPZygBBXX04jwwuoyn89IgAJJNZSJZZ7FZwMEAzC4AhEKChCLcKIxeLEJGQ6GJWGjeFwaoowLo0gocgASncdAAvoz6GFFNwAMbRWK%20FAAcUUOjwADEMNzoIgEokXg4oOF1M1OcAKQE0SFwpEeXiSXTXgA3bCKFVwaSIOnUZKGrDG-KUYhpByc2IcODWqnQcivF5gKAQFCwRAo43VM0WqjJB7cOkZepUOAAeREACtgNyAHRFciy0ny4HyrnABx09PKDBgF5FS2O0nO7iuvOKwvB1Dxl5xM2JRsF5Uxw6M%20HkADuUU5AAs4C9u0rgC2LelSYxORhyKhjB1%20JU4Xt5TBFFBuG7q0gUCU3ZM41R4%20v%20gOycvV-dxBcZFvFzvgHuD0eI3zgGf9QvagryfGxpFYO94QfNdtlYN8yQ-L9D31Y8yAAoCr2vWDIL2aDehMYY4O3Rhd33ZDq0Aj4QKULAsGYFgT3-UpKLqYDryGfgcKXFc1yjCx4IQuBSO-FDfxYqZgPmRRaPov90KokDRGfW4uLgPC1hURZ%20OIoTPzIn8rQw%20MaLopgGLQ5ijKwzSNlUvBwgwaSYAEhCAHpXLgIdUB0VBuAgeBxWVMBoj4KTaNcjl7KxYA8DgMJoAaZRgryHRwXTdK4AAZTHCBpNi%20zOXwVAcqHBAIB09y4DHaQ8EkVy6wiXh91QGAx1QcgUEKiJOTUnidJwUoXgJdMcHIAkpwVHtZyNYA6XnHSlxdAL-kJYBlEpdUoBSRjBWFMUJSgKVOwm-MZxbDIAAZygZBbdKQgzERWkaxpWl5xOuuAADJPvPQ502AfV1EQF5Uv0KE1o2oIoBu99GCZCqPOIBNggTapqpaSQ4CixysHgaCdOEw8AH1ROSMJsFXHD4bkJkYZIvTvzembxj1N0ZrtMpLWWJmbVQb62dRKHyH%20wHDp5j0trEtUoZ5405otMy4op4BGWp%20g61dd1NpFEJCAwJNU25bayF2qBRXFdFgdSLG9eqG8%20AGWnWToDX4CaDgAGEeK9NIBZDU1uEQVxPk6po8GqKM4CZWMUgyBxretf2TIAGhDtMw%20qcmsEfJlk-jv2TUizVuBi1OvHTmLM%20VqO87kBPmd9tEMGqC6a7T7lK6V7PUFz-PE5Na2m7ti7HbL8AK-DhAoFtanymd92YC91dhfiqAAFFxTHF4F6X1tkgXRb6zdigYAAJQoJyUi1qGdYxPWDfT7eT939N%207p-JBoX8-yEvzCEGfni-1x4dzwPNWsLobAjW4PFF4AADTKihOTKnIJQF4I5WoFzgAAElSF-C%20uNaawNTjvQBb87xMgaN3GsUEIGSH%20roaAcCxQ4DomgqIE5%207YNwSfb%20TlCHEIAauV%20M137Uydh4OgPAmhQHJsqREflWrqBpKgA%20cAOIAAU-RgGqBxO82xNH%20mqNsO8UYDHaLgFGPR0ksAYBEJITKBFeBmLMDoxxVjaK2MkAAORslAZxRjfHuJsXY4AAAhZS0h-EWIidwO8oNEBmOqKoxgQ81FuIcNHOe9A1YuyWgLCWt8fgKLalAZRxsBRCjNvtS2cQin%20RKcomUqiNFaLthxVgtdGD6NaQoXxHSHCmJ6UpMCMhOlhWCfYxxiT8IbgsGMkynjgA%20OcH4oZ2w5kOAWSE8JIzpnDJfBsuQ8Tplx1JMkvYqT7b8GWNTRg5Rskw3Vnkkhy8ABMSSC6hkDsHcuICI4xKjjHeMpzGD115gE2iY9Q6dyzjnMZYL-ZF2ingKFE8q5UN7nXT5jdbZwFbrnduGcu5wvjssfuSTtwtMMTM-oYz4TdOpQARjpXsQZ1LODGhZV06xiyHEbj2e0rl4zFnLMWNM5l24tmSB2S%20aZsLgBCuOT0jIg9cWsEdvc0kmL4S-KJRyosNN4VkobucxgVLzFXP6e%20Bl5iJXvjZeY-VQqpXAD5aYaZKdJU8pCaK9QHrrHOu9dKmJ-rIXbiVdS2MNyWW6s7vqjJRrSTkuoWSc1bTHFWoQja6odqEIOuqE6r1HiQlur4AKjNgbi3eN8aGrAlaJlhJDT0z174I3mJVTbGAzc2CjxxV2u2vbVX9rxVHTV8JtV7FjZPeVCbSVJpNZSqZQzBVepWeKoV%20ap6cqLQ20tTjl0Vp3SKmtzaA1Hu2U26lLaEJtuqB2y5g7O3dvVW3Id3b8Vjr2BOxgU70WrlnXXY14KU2DiXVes91qT1Mo3Zex108FXnsmfy09YbINVqWVB8x16yQuplbYWtiqVonM-XDGNwCiUzppvQLJdB6AvIoK89Mq8N7jifp7Hi1ZVGu3-hwXhuMr7S3RIU4pSiyBscXqQkRd4BqTjwT-fjf96NAOhaAkDalaHACgTA%20BiDkGoPQRw9mOC5N8LpEQnjEmhFkIyZQx85yNaQPUH6KATCMAsMnAZzBxmeH4JgPwizL9rNUeZDDIAA).

Comment: It's actually `KISSANTS`, where `ANTS` stands for `and not type safe`

Comment: Than write a type guard which is type safe (that is, that knows the type of what is passed on). Good luck with that.

Comment: "Than write a type guard which is type safe" --- tbh, in my code bases all type guards are type safe and I have zero `any` or other unsafe casts. It's just this case that TS type system is not capable to express easily.

Comment: Ok, so could please share an example? I'm genuinely curious on how you access a property of `unknown` when you don't know it exists. I'm not kidding: if it's possible, I want to know how it's done.

Comment: So am I @A.Chiesa, that's why I asked this question :)

Comment: @A.Chiesa I don't think it's possible with the current TS type system tools (I'm not a TS expert though). In my apps no type guards presumably type assert objects (I use `io-ts` for that), and for primitive types it's possible to use `unknown` only.

Comment: @Adam you can throw whatever you want to the guard I wrote: it will not throw and it will return true only if the object has a `data` property of type string. I don't know what's more safe. It's _not_ type safe, however, but my point is you don't need to. This is the ONLY place you need to use any: because you can't use unknown if you need to access the object.

Comment: Now we're coming somewhere :-D I like your effort though!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after googling and discussing it with somebody else I came to this solution:

```js
type DataObject = {
  data: string
};

function isDataObjectLike(v: unknown): v is { [K in keyof DataObject]: unknown } {
  return typeof v === 'object'
    && v !== null
    && 'data' in v;
}

function hasDataProperty(v: unknown): v is DataObject {
  return isDataObjectLike(v)
    && typeof v.data === 'string';
}
```

[typescript/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOB5ARgKwgY2FAvFAbwFgAoKKAEwTgC4oBnYAJwEsA7Ac1IF8BuU0gDMArm2wsA9mygt68RKgzYAMiwDWEABQA3OqLVsJAdzYBKOtpn1CUANoBpGdI0gJg2NUVZgAXT1sDY2luQlJyJghgYSZpUEg3KEtcZKgAcgl0b1Sw8igAMjzEqABCFLZhABsKnPICtKpEVKdE-hJuARIRMWBJaQALODlqAAUmCUgmUB1-QJNzItkPBUzsULIoCKiYq3lkFeBVDR1TGvzCuIgE7QA6Brg8FNTGVk5U1u4gA)

Not that it is *significantly* better than the one with `any` but it provides more safety from the compiler.

Comment: What kind of safety? `any` is not a demon: it means just plain JavaScript for 1 line of code. YMMV, so, if you prefer this way, do it, but I see a lot more possible bugs in this implementation than in mine.

Comment: @A.Chiesa share any?

Comment: I asked first ;) what kind of safety? You still have the burden of checking every single property, spelling it correctly, and your checks are EXACTLY the same as `obj && typeof obj.data === 'string'`. What is better and effectively more safe?

Comment: @A.Chiesa "and your checks are EXACTLY the same as" --- tinyurl.com/yy7l4pk7 tinyurl.com/y6pfrkox (sorry for tinyurl, the links are too long) On the links you can see the case when a little change in the initial interface makes my solution type safer.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using the "in" operator? [Doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator)

```
type DataObject = {
  data: string
};

function hasDataProperty(myObject: any): myObject is DataObject {
    return "data" in myObject
}

let a = {data: 'a'}
if (hasDataProperty(a)) {
  console.log(a.data); //
} else {
  console.log(a.data); //error
}
```

Seems like it exactly does what you want except that it does not check the type.

Just to make sure I'd add another type check like this:

```
function hasDataProperty(myObject: any): myObject is DataObject {
    return "data" in myObject && typeof myObject.data === 'string'
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry for cheating. Now with a two step approach:

```
type DataObject = {
  data: string
};

function hasDataProperty(myObject: unknown): myObject is DataObject {
  function hasDataPropertyAny(myObject: any): myObject is DataObject {
    return "data" in myObject && typeof myObject.data === 'string';
  }
  if (!!myObject && typeof myObject === 'object') {
    return hasDataPropertyAny(myObject);
  } 
  return false;
}

const tests = [
  { data: 'foobar' } as unknown,
  { data: 42 } as unknown,
  42,
  null,
  undefined
]
tests.forEach((a: unknown) => {
  if (hasDataProperty(a)) {
    console.log('DataObject value: ', a.data);
  } else {
    console.log('Not a DataObject!')
  }
})
```

Comment: My personal tip would also be to use `unknown` not `any` in type guards.

Comment: Your method works because the `myObject` argument is of type `any`, not `unknown`. If possible, I would prefer to use `unknown`, since `any` opens up a lot more roof for mistakes, which I indicated in my question.

Comment: Well, I would say unknown is perfectly useless in a type guard: you are effectively "sniffing" the type using only plain JavaScript.

Comment: "unknown is perfectly useless in a type guard" --- it's the opposite: `unknown` is extremely useful because it protects you from making assumptions `any` allows you to do. "you are effectively "sniffing" the type using only plain JavaScript." --- exactly, that's the very point of the `unknown` type.

Comment: A type guard is NOT type safe. It makes _the rest_ of the code type safe. Do not overestimate the power of unknown: it allows you to not call properties which are not known to be present. But the WHOLE POINT of a type guard id to check if a "something" conforms to an interface. And the only way you do it is peeking into it for properties that are not known to exist (yet!).

Comment: "A type guard is NOT type safe" --- a type guard implementation **must be** type safe. It's its job to ensure a value is of a particular type and **guarantee** to never throw in runtime.

Comment: Oh my. "Type safe" means that your code is safe because it knows about the type of what is using. A type guard doesn't know what is using, and is necessary so the rest of your code can be type safe. However, the bit about "guarantee to never throw in runtime" is correct: a type guard must manage everything that can be thrown at it.

Comment: @A.Chiesa without "type safety" the implementation is not **guaranteed** to not throw, you just hope you did not miss some edge case. "A type guard doesn't know what is using" --- that's correct, that's why `unknown` type was introduced.